# Django Taggit error "too many SQL variables" how can i do limit query?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

Hello i have a wallpaper website. Im using taggit. I have 200k tags and have 20k wallpaper.

I want use related wallpapers in view like this

```
def detail(request,slug):

    wallpaper = get_object_or_404(Wallpapers, slug = slug)
    category = Category.objects.all()
    similar_posts = wallpaper.tags.similar_objects()[:20]
    random.shuffle(similar_posts)
    return render(request, "detail.html", {"wallpaper": wallpaper, "category": category, "similar_posts": similar_posts,  })
```

and i take "too many SQL variables" error.

example wallpaper tags: 
**anime, water, rain**

15k+ wallpaper have **anime** tag

How can i limit or filter query this related wallpaper items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I FOUND SOLUTION LIKE THIS**

```
 similar_posts = wallpaper.tags.similar_objects()[:20]
 random.shuffle(similar_posts)
```

change to;

```
 similar_posts = Wallpapers.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [wallpaper.tags.names()]).order_by('?')[:20]
```